# paparse showing extra object after parsing csv file data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

I'm Using paparse to parse csv file data into json format , it is working fine , but whenever i we paparse parse the csv file data into jason array of objects , it shows extra object with null values, for example , if we upload csv with 4 records , papaparse will convert it into array of object of length 5 , in which 5 object is with empty fields , as you can see in console below

below function converts csv file text to json array of objects

```
checkCsvValidation = async (file, csvData) => {
    const text = await file.text()
    let result = parse(text, { header: true })
    console.log("Text => ", text)
    console.log("result => ", result.data)
}
```

Console of Text =>

First Name,Last Name,Email,Contact,Graduation Year,Position Played,Jersey Number,Instagram Account,Twitter Account

Gautam,Gambhir,pranjalnimkar032@gmail.com,5476587681,2018,Position-6,2,instagram.com,twitter.com

Suresh,Raina,pranjalnimkar123@gmail.com,5476587681,2014,Position-6,2,instagram.com,twitter.com

Shreyas,Iyyer,gautamibanerjee889@gmail.com,5476587681,2018,Position-6,2,instagram.com,twitter.com

Mohammad,Shami,gautamibanerjee89@gmail.com,5476587681,2018,Position-6,2,instagram.com,twitter.com

Sachin,Tendulkar,gauamibanerje889@gmail.com,5476587681,2018,Position-6,2,instagram.com,twitter.com

---

Console of Result after using parse =>

```
[
  {
    "First Name": "Gautam",
    "Last Name": "Gambhir",
    "Email": "pranjalnimkar032@gmail.com",
    "Contact": "5476587681",
    "Graduation Year": "2018",
    "Position Played": "Position-6",
    "Jersey Number": "2",
    "Instagram Account": "instagram.com",
    "Twitter Account": "twitter.com"
  },
  {
    "First Name": "Suresh",
    "Last Name": "Raina",
    "Email": "pranjalnimkar123@gmail.com",
    "Contact": "5476587681",
    "Graduation Year": "2014",
    "Position Played": "Position-6",
    "Jersey Number": "2",
    "Instagram Account": "instagram.com",
    "Twitter Account": "twitter.com"
  },
  {
    "First Name": "Shreyas",
    "Last Name": "Iyyer",
    "Email": "gautamibanerjee889@gmail.com",
    "Contact": "5476587681",
    "Graduation Year": "2018",
    "Position Played": "Position-6",
    "Jersey Number": "2",
    "Instagram Account": "instagram.com",
    "Twitter Account": "twitter.com"
  },
  {
    "First Name": "Mohammad",
    "Last Name": "Shami",
    "Email": "gautamibanerjee89@gmail.com",
    "Contact": "5476587681",
    "Graduation Year": "2018",
    "Position Played": "Position-6",
    "Jersey Number": "2",
    "Instagram Account": "instagram.com",
    "Twitter Account": "twitter.com"
  },
  {
    "First Name": "Sachin",
    "Last Name": "Tendulkar",
    "Email": "gauamibanerje889@gmail.com",
    "Contact": "5476587681",
    "Graduation Year": "2018",
    "Position Played": "Position-6",
    "Jersey Number": "2",
    "Instagram Account": "instagram.com",
    "Twitter Account": "twitter.com"
  },
  {
    "First Name": ""
  }// i'm getting this extra object with empty fields after using parse of papaparse
]
```

Please Help me to solve this issue

Comment: try this: let result = parse(text, { header: true, skipEmptyLines: true })